# how to get json results from xml document in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am trying to return an XML document in JSON format using a 2-tier server side javascript application. I know MarkLogic can easily switch between JSON and XML formats using the REST api.

However, the following returns xml:

```
cts.search('something', ['format-xml']) // options may be omitted
```

but this returns nothing:

```
cts.search('something', ['format-json'])
```

According to the documentation I think I have used the function correctly.

Is this possible using server side javascript?

**Update:**

Using `transformToJsonObject` as follows:

```
var json = require('/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy');
var doc = fn.doc('/content/rss/72eb9bf835521446be8d2176e1ac9d22.xml')
var jsonDoc = json.transformToJsonObject(doc, json.config('custom'));
jsonDoc
```

I get the following error:

```
500 Internal Server Error

XDMP-STACKOVERFLOW: Stack overflow
in /MarkLogic/json/custom.xqy, at 493:23,
in json-custom:is-ignore-attribute#2(json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"><json:entry key="element-qname-from-json-name"><json:value xsi:t...</json:object>...XDMP-ATOMIZEFUNC: (err:FOTY0013) Functions cannot be atomized...), fn:doc("/content/rss/72eb9bf835521446be8d2176e1ac9d22.xml")/newsitem/article/*:html/*:head/*:script[5]/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:link/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:style/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:link/*:script/*:script/*:noscript/*:link/*:meta/*:body/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:noscript/*:p/*:header/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:a/*:section/*:div/*:h2/*:ul/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:a/*:img/*:span/*:script/*:nav/*:div/*:h2/*:ul/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:div/*:a/*:form/*:div/*:label/*:div/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:a/*:svg/*:title/*:h2/*:a/*:div/*:button/*:div/*:ul/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:div/*:nav/*:a/*:span/*:span/*:ul/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:span/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:span/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h1/*:div/*:ul/*:li/*:div/*:li/*:span/*:a/*:div/*:figure/*:span/*:img/*:span/*:span/*:figcaption/*:span/*:span/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:h2/*:p/*:p/*:figure/*:span/*:div/*:span/*:span/*:figcaption/*:span/*:span/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:h2/*:a/*:ul/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:li/*:a/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h2/*:div/*:ul/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:li/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h2/*:div/*:ul/*:li/*:div/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:span/*:p/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:h2/*:a/*:strong/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:strong/*:div/*:a/*:strong/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:script/*:script/*:div/*:div/*:h2/*:div/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h3/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h3/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h3/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h3/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h3/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h3/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:h3/*:p/*:div/*:a/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:div/*:span/*:span/*:span/*:h3/@class) [1.0-ml]
$config = json:object(<json:object xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"><json:entry key="element-qname-from-json-name"><json:value xsi:t...</json:object>...XDMP-ATOMIZEFUNC: (err:FOTY0013) Functions cannot be atomized...)
$a = fn:doc("/content/rss/72eb9bf835521446be8d2176e1ac9d22.xml")/newsitem/article/*:html/*:head/*:script[5]/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:link/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:style/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:script/*:scr
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `format-xml` and `format-json` options to `cts.search()` filter the search results by those formats; they don't do any transformations (see the [`cts.search()` options documentation](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.search#options)).

There are many ways to transform XML into JSON using MarkLogic; the simplest is probably the [`json` XQuery library](http://docs.marklogic.com/json/json), specifically [`json:transform-to-json-object()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/json:transform-to-json-object). You can use that library in server-side JS like this:

```
var json = require('/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy');

var doc = cts.doc('/triplestore/97a5ab126bddeea0.xml');
var jsonDoc = json.transformToJsonObject(doc, json.config('custom'));
```

You can use [`json.config()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/json:config) to configure and customize the transformation.

`cts.search()` returns an `Iterator`, so you'll need a `for-of` loop (or some kind of accumulator function) to get the actual XML documents, which you could then transform.

**Update**:

That error could be a bug in the JSON library, but that's a very deep HTML path; and I don't think it makes much sense to transform HTML elements into JSON object properties. Instead, we'll serialize the HTML, and add the string back to our JSON object.

Here's an example transformation of search results; showing how to unwrap the `Iterator`, customize the JSON transformations, serialize XHTML content for use within JSON, etc.

Notes:

- this uses `fn.subsequence` to limit the `Iterator` to the first 10 results.
- I'm serializing the excluded `<html/>` elements to a string (using the [`xpath()` method of the Node object](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_32220) and [`xdmp.quote()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.quote), and adding that to the JSON object as `escapedContent`.

Here's the combined example; you can run this in MarkLogic QConsole:

```
var json = require('/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy');
var conf = json.config('custom');

var htmlNs = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';

// exclude <html:html/> elements

// Note: this is a little awkward because the JSON library is XQuery
// and requires an XDM sequence, not an Array
conf['ignore-element-names'] = json.arrayValues([
  fn.QName(htmlNs, 'html')
]);

var results = fn.subsequence(
  cts.search(cts.andQuery(null), 'format-xml'),
  1,
  10
);

var transformedResults = [];
var transformed = [];

for (var result of results) {
  // transformToJson() returns an object-node() wrapped in a document-node()
  // convert it to a regular JS object
  transformed = json.transformToJson(result, conf).toObject()

  transformed.escapedContent = xdmp.quote(
    result.xpath('.//html:html', { html: htmlNs}) 
  );

  transformedResults.push(transformed);
}

transformedResults
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have tried but does not work for me yet. Funnily enough I keep getting an XDMP:STACKOVERFLOW error. Its probably something to do with my data though. I will keep trying and if I get it working I'll accept.

Comment: Can you update your answer and post the full error message? Also, I've updated my answer with a search iteration example.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the error. FYI, The xml document contains one child which has "tidy" html in the body.

Comment: Wow, that's a crazy deep path. You probably want that HTML to be a string, not each element as a JSON property. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This is an extremely helpful answer in every way! I can't thank you enough.

Comment: Thanks, that's great to hear. Best of luck!